# React: Is a component entirely re-rendered on every setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just got a bit confused about the lifecycle in react.
Here's my understanding...

> The `render()` always run first, right? If so...
>   It implies that a `setState()` inside `useEffect()` only runs after the initial `render()`, correct?

Question:
When the above happens, does the entire component re-render?
So that would be a second time the component renders just to load a `state`.
 
Wouldn't that be a performance issue?

Comment: I thought React only re-rendered the sub-elements that change, not *all* elements.

Comment: I see, so only the sub-elements that depend on that state will re render when the state changes? Did i get it correctly?

Comment: I've *heard* something along those lines, not 100% sure though.

Comment: renders are usually super fast, unless you huge DOM structure. Also, only the changed parts go to the DOM anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On every state change render is called again but not whole component renders again.

React keeps Two DOM Tree Objects in memory:

1. Virtual DOM
2. Real DOM

React have a very intelligent and powerful diffing algorithm which calculates difference between previous DOM `state` and Next DOM `state` called **Reconciliation** process.

Only those sub elements which have changed would be re-rendered.
Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.
Keys should added to `list` or `array` elements , to give those elements a stable identity

[image]

For example, you want to delete `<input key="i42"/>` element from your list so on left side Its **Actual DOM Tree Object** and on Right side its **Virtual DOM tree object**. React calculates difference between two and only the difference will be Recreated Intelligently.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

So the thing about React is that there are two DOMs -- one is the actual DOM, and the other is the virtual DOM. Every time there is a state change, the virtual DOM re-renders. React then compares the changes to the virtual DOM vs changes to the real DOM, and only updates the real DOM with what has actually changed. 
Re-rendering the virtual DOM is not a performance issue as it's super quick.

There's a cool [article](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-virtual-dom-explained/) you can read about this